# WordPress phone Number Restrict to allow xxx-xxx-xxxx Format

Tags: wordpress, contact-form, phone-number, tel

I have Kept the placeholder as xxx-xxx-xxxx

```
<label> Phone Number </label> [number* shm-mrk-phone minlength:10 maxlength:140 placeholder "]
```

I changes the tel script in plugin formatting.php

```
function wpcf7_is_tel( $tel ) {
    $result = preg_match( '/^(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$/', $tel );
    return apply_filters( 'wpcf7_is_tel', $result, $tel );
}
```

its not allowing xxx-xxx-xxxx( this should allow), its allowing xxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Very Simple. i used `tel` instead of number Type to add Mobile Number.

In Contact Form 7 plugin formatting.php Module,

i updated the Code of `wpcf7_is_tel` function with.

```
function wpcf7_is_tel( $tel ) {
    $result = preg_match( '/^(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$/', $tel );
    return apply_filters( 'wpcf7_is_tel', $result, $tel );
}
```

Works Fine.